# How to use a colon in lstlisting keywords?

Tags: listings, keywords, css

for the use of CSS code I've defined the following style:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{CSS}{
    sensitive=true,
    alsodigit={-},
    keywords={transform, transition-property, transition-duration, transition-timing-functio},              
    morecomment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]"
}
```

In CSS3 `transform` can be a keyword and a property. Therefore, both variations are shown in blue in my document.

**Screenshot:**

[image: s]

Keywords always end with a colon. Can this rule be used to prevent the properties being marked as keyword?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.95}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{0.4, 0.4, 0.4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}

\lstdefinelanguage{CSS}{
    keywords={color,background-image,margin,padding,font,weight,display,position,top,left,right,bottom,list,style,border,size,white,space,min,width, transform, transition, transition-property, transition-duration, transition-timing-function},
    alsodigit={-},
    sensitive=true,
    morecomment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]"
}

\lstset{%
    % General design
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},   
    frame=l,
    % Code design
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{greenCode}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{ocherCode}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{darkgray}\ttfamily,
    % Code
    language={CSS},
    tabsize=2,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true,
    % line-numbers
    xleftmargin={0.75cm},
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    firstnumber=1,
    numberfirstline=true,
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}
        #box {
            transition-property: transform;
            transition-duration: 2s;
            transition-timing-function: linear;
      }
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My current solution is to **put a colon at the end** of all the keywords and to use `alsoletter={-}` and `alsodigit={:}`.

**Example:**

```
\lstdefinelanguage{CSS}{
    keywords={transform:, transition-property:, transition-duration:, transition-timing-function:},
    sensitive=true,
    morecomment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]",        
    alsoletter={-},
    alsodigit={:}
}
```

It is very annoying but it works. It would be better if one could define everything as a keyword that is between a space and a colon.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

As suggested by [Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel), the answer to your question is **yes**. Using `moredelim=[s][]{:}{;}` should do the trick, and there is no longer any need to change anything in your code. This way, anything in between and including `:` and `;` are typeset in black.

### Original Post

You can use `moredelim=[is][\bfseries]{/@}{@/}` in `\lstdefinelanguage` or `\lstset`. Here, the *delimeters* `/@` and `@/` are used. (You can change them with a character or combination of characters not used in the language.) They will not appear in the output but typesets any character in between them, in this case, as boldface.

#### The Code

Here is the full code with the parts I inserted commented.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.95}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{0.4, 0.4, 0.4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}

\lstdefinelanguage{CSS}{
    keywords={color,background-image,margin,padding,font,weight,display,position,top,left,right,bottom,list,style,border,size,white,space,min,width, transform, transition, transition-property, transition-duration, transition-timing-function},
    alsodigit={-},
    sensitive=true,
    morecomment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]",
    moredelim=[is][\bfseries]{/@}{@/}, % Typesets characters between /@ and @/ delimeters in boldface.
}

\lstset{%
    % General design
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},   
    frame=l,
    % Code design
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{greenCode}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{ocherCode}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{darkgray}\ttfamily,
    % Code
    language={CSS},
    tabsize=2,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true,
    % line-numbers
    xleftmargin={0.75cm},
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    firstnumber=1,
    numberfirstline=true,
}

% See how the delimeters are used below.
\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}
        #box {
            transition-property: /@transform@/;
            transition-duration: 2s;
            transition-timing-function: linear;
      }
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

#### The Output

[image]

Comment: I’d go so far and use `moredelim=[s][]{:}{;}`: No change of input. Text between (and including) `:` and `;` always caught and not in blue.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, you are right. I will update my answer accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this great help. Unfortunately mmoredelim=[s][]{:}{;} has some side effects. The word "transform" can be a property and a keyword. The keyword is "transform:" and the property is "transform". If I declare "transform" in the keyword list and if I use "transform: translate (100px , 100 px);" in my code, then transform is not blue anymore because of moredelim=[s][]{:}{;} :-(

Comment: I thought you wanted that part after the colon black. Well, it seems you already have solved your problem.